# Make MetroJS responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, microsoft-metro

I'm using MetroJS (http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) and its working well. 
But now I want to make the Metro layout responsive for mobile devices and so on.

Normally I would say I rearrange the tiles with the @media tag. But since the property about the tile size is in the class tag its not working that way or?

```html
<div class="tiles tile-group five-tall six-wide">
```

Furthermore it would be awesome to make a animation while resizing the window like in the example:
http://themeforest.net/item/matrix-responsive-tilebased-template/full_screen_preview/2761654

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create different sizes for your tiles at different screen sizes you can use the theme generator to do this. Just click 'add' under the Size Options and it will create a new media query for you
http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs/theme-generator

.live-tile can be sized to whatever you would like to implement you own responsive. I started a responsive version of the tile layouts but have not had time to finalize it or test enough to include it in a release.
http://www.drewgreenwell.com/scripts/metrojs/src/css/responsive.css
As I move towards GSAP, I plan to build responsive in from the start rather than adaptive.

If you want animated movement of tiles as you resize your browser window (nice, but useful?), then I would recommend using something like Isotope or Masonry for your layout.

- Isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
- Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Probably worth noting that the theme you linked is using Metro JS (LiveTile) with Masonry for the layout